# How to convert a Pytorch model architecture string into a Tree data structure?

Tags: javascript, python, recursion, data-structures

## Goal / Problem:

---

I am currently trying to challenge my self and wanted to see if I could reverse a pytorch models architecture, based off its output string alone. I have gotten most the way through, but I end up getting locked in recursion hell (Things not working as they should recursively) and end up restarting from scratch. Its been around 3 days now of trying to tackle this idea and I cant seem to figure out a way to do it.

## What I have tried:

---

- Parsing each line into its components, `offset`, `name`, `layer`
- Using the `offset` parameter of the line to control flow of the recursion
- Using the `)` characters to know when a block has finished to control the flow of the recursion

Each way I do these, I end up having some issue, and its hard to figure out how to fix it as the method is recursive and the structure of pytorch models vary in blocks, sequential layers, etc.

I think parsing each line into its components was a great start because it simplifies the problem. I developed a basic tree data structure that fits what I will be using it for:

I want to do this in javascript as I want to be able to input a string of a pytorch model as a form, and beable to output the tree on a website. Think it would be pretty neat (Long term goal :) )

Atleast the parsing each line code works great.

## Code

---

### Tree Data Structure

```js
class TreeNode {
  constructor(name, type) {
    this.name = name; // Layer name - ex. 'conv1', 'conv2', 'bn2', 'fc' etc.
    this.type = type; // Layer type (After :) - ex. 'ReLU(inplace=True)' etc.
    this.children = [];
    this.parent = null;
  }

  addChild(node) {
    if (!(node instanceof TreeNode)) {
      throw new Error('Invalid node. Node must be an instance of TreeNode.');
    }

    node.parent = this;
    this.children.push(node);
  }

  removeChild(node) {
    const index = this.children.indexOf(node);
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.children.splice(index, 1);
      node.parent = null;
    }
  }

  getChild(index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.children.length) {
      throw new Error('Index out of bounds.');
    }

    return this.children[index];
  }

  getChildren() {
    return this.children;
  }

  getParent() {
    return this.parent;
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  getType() {
    return this.type;
  }
}
```

### Parsing code

```js
function parseLine(line) {
  const matches = line.match(/^(\s*)(?:\()?(.*?)(?:\))?(:\s+)(.*)$/)
  if (matches) { // Offset code counts spaces and /2 to get have a number (depth level)
      return {offset: matches[1].substring(4).length/2, name: matches[2], type: matches[4]};
  }
}

function parseInput(input) {
  linesParsed = []
  lines = input.split("\n") 
  lines.shift()// Shift gets rid of first entry
  lines.forEach(line => {
    const parsedLine = parseLine(line)
    if (!(parsedLine == null)) {
      linesParsed.push(parseLine(line))
    }
  });
  console.log(linesParsed)
  const rootNode = new TreeNode('model');
  generateTree(linesParsed, rootNode);
  return rootNode;
}

function generateTree(linesParsed, node) {
  // Recursive fun here ...
}
```

### Sample string input (Good ol' Resnet):

```
ResNet(
    (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (layer1): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (layer2): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (layer3): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (layer4): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
    (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think recursion is necessary here. A simple (not really) loop should be all you need (I neglected using the getters for simplicity sake, feel free to add it in again):

```js
function generateTree(linesParsed, node) {
  let lastOffset = -1 // this helps us track the steps to move
  for (const line of linesParsed) {
    const curr = new TreeNode(line.name, line.type)

    if (line.offset < lastOffset) {
      // go back up
      const steps = lastOffset - line.offset
      let target = node.parent
      for(let i = 0; i < steps; i++) target = target.parent
      
      target.addChild(curr)
    } else if (line.offset === lastOffset) // sibling
      node.parent.addChild(curr)
    else node.addChild(curr) // child
    lastOffset = line.offset
    node = curr // store reference to last node
  }
}
```

Demo:

```js
class TreeNode {
  constructor(name, type) {
    this.name = name; // Layer name - ex. 'conv1', 'conv2', 'bn2', 'fc' etc.
    this.type = type; // Layer type (After :) - ex. 'ReLU(inplace=True)' etc.
    this.children = [];
    this.parent = null;
  }

  addChild(node) {
    if (!(node instanceof TreeNode)) {
      throw new Error('Invalid node. Node must be an instance of TreeNode.');
    }

    node.parent = this;
    this.children.push(node);
  }

  removeChild(node) {
    const index = this.children.indexOf(node);
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.children.splice(index, 1);
      node.parent = null;
    }
  }
}

function parseLine(line) {
  const matches = line.match(/^(\s*)(?:\()?(.*?)(?:\))?(:\s+)(.*)$/)
  if (matches) { // Offset code counts spaces and /2 to get have a number (depth level)
    return { offset: matches[1].substring(4).length / 2, name: matches[2], type: matches[4] };
  }
}

function parseInput(input) {
  linesParsed = []
  lines = input.split("\n")
  lines.shift()
  let count = 0;
  lines.forEach(line => {
    const parsedLine = parseLine(line)
    count += 1;
    if (!(parsedLine == null)) {
      linesParsed.push(parseLine(line))
    }
  });
  const rootNode = new TreeNode('model');
  generateTree(linesParsed, rootNode);
  return rootNode;
}

function generateTree(linesParsed, node) {
  let lastOffset = -1
  for (const line of linesParsed) {
    const curr = new TreeNode(line.name, line.type)
    if (line.offset < lastOffset) {
      const steps = lastOffset - line.offset
      let target = node.parent
      for(let i = 0; i < steps; i++) target = target.parent
      
      target.addChild(curr)
    } else if (line.offset === lastOffset)
      node.parent.addChild(curr)
    else node.addChild(curr)
    lastOffset = line.offset
    node = curr
  }
}

const result = parseInput(`ResNet(
    (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
    (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (layer1): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (layer2): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (layer3): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (layer4): Sequential(
      (0): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (downsample): Sequential(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
          (1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        )
      )
      (1): BasicBlock(
        (conv1): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
        (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
    (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)
  )`)
 
// to prevent circular reference
function removeParent(node) {
  delete node.parent
  // just because unclosed parens are horrid
  if(node?.type?.endsWith?.("(")) node.type = node.type.slice(0, -1)
  node.children.forEach(removeParent)
  if(!node.children.length) delete node.children
}
removeParent(result)

document.querySelector("pre").innerText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: This is such an elegant way of solving this problem. I was stuck trying to use such a complex method when I never even considered using a similar looping method. Thank you so much! This works perfectly and gets the right result everytime!

Comment: You even tackled the issue of the disgusting open '(' !

Comment: @Baxtrax definitely relatable, glad it helped! Happy coding!